# How to simultaneously update an Access database and a .NET DataSet object using the DataAdapter.Update method?

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset, connection-string, oledb

I have imported an Access database into my Visual Studio 2008 project (written in C#), it reads the table fields from data source, but when updating it only does in the `DataSet` object and not the actual database.

Here is my code:

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var cb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

     DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["ever"].NewRow();

     dRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
     dRow[2] = textBox1.Text;
     dRow[3] = textBox1.Text;

     ds1.Tables["ever"].Rows.Add(dRow);

     da.Update(ds1, "ever");

     MessageBox.Show("Record added");
 }
```

However, the following exception is displayed:

> "The ConnectionString property has not
>   been initialized."

In this line:

```
da.Update(ds1, "ever");
```

Comment: You will have to show us how 'da' is declared and initialized.

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;

Comment: And where do you instantiate da?

Comment: Instantiating is:   da = new OleDbDataAdapter (..);

Answer (score 0):

The Update method uses the command you specify in the UpdateCommand property. I suspect that is part of your problem. There is probably a similar property for the connection string for each of the commands (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).